# PowerShell special characters encoding

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I've built a PS script to create and populate items from a CSV file. The issue is that chars like ä, ü, ö are replaced with � in the field values. I've changed the encoding from `ConvertToDynamicObject()` function from '`Default`' to '`UTF8`', without luck.

The function to read the CSV:

```
function ReadCSV($media)
{
    # get stream and save content to variable $content
    [System.IO.Stream]$body = $media.Fields["Blob"].GetBlobStream()
    try    
    {
        $contents = New-Object byte[] $body.Length
        $body.Read($contents, 0, $body.Length) | Out-Null
    }
    
    finally 
    {
        $body.Close()    
    }
    
    return $contents;
}
```

Then I convert the byte[] to a Dynamic object:

```
function ConvertToDynamicObject($contents)
{
    # convert to dynamic object
    return $csv = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($contents) | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","
}
```

Then process the data:

```
function ImportItem($csv)
{
    foreach ($row in $csv)
    {
        # ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your source file uses an encoding different from `UTF8` or your system default. Please double check the encoding of the file your are uploading into the Media Library and then use the same encoding in PowerShell script. If your CSV file was created in Excel, most likely you will need `Windows-1252` encoding.

I have tested your code with a CSV file similar to this:

> Column1,Column2
>
> äää,äää
>
> üüü,üüü

On my machine, a file in `ANSI` encoding works well with the line
`[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($contents)`,
`UTF-8` file works with the line `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($contents)`, and Excel-generated CSV file in `Windows-1252` encoding works only with the line `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString($contents)`. All other combinations produce an incorrect result.

For reference, here is the full script that I used:

```
function ReadCSV($media)
{
    [System.IO.Stream]$body = $media.Fields["Blob"].GetBlobStream()
    try    
    {
        $contents = New-Object byte[] $body.Length
        $body.Read($contents, 0, $body.Length) | Out-Null
    }
    
    finally 
    {
        $body.Close()    
    }
    
    return $contents;
}

function ConvertToDynamicObject($contents)
{
    return $csv = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString($contents) | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","
}

function ImportItem($csv)
{
    foreach ($row in $csv)
    {
        Write-Host $row.Column1, $row.Column2
        $item = Get-Item "master:/content/home"
        $newItem = New-Item -Parent $item -Name $row.Column1 -ItemType "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
        $newItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
        $newItem["Title"] = $row.Column2
        $newItem.Editing.EndEdit()
    }
}

$csvMediaItem = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/media library/Files/test-excel"
$csvContent = ReadCSV($csvMediaItem)
$csvDynamicObject = ConvertToDynamicObject($csvContent)
ImportItem($csvDynamicObject)
```

This is the result I got with the above script and sample CSV:
[image: Sitecore items with special characters]

Comment: It worked. Thanks Anna!